# Strange problems with PHP SOAP (private variable not persist + variables passed from client not working)

Tags: php, soap

I have a very strange problems in a PHP Soap implementation.

1) I have a private variable in the Server class which contains the DB name for further reference. The private variable name is "fromdb". I have a public function on the soap server where I can set this variable. $client->setFromdb. When I call it form my client works perfectly and the fromdb private variable can be set. But a second soap client call this private variable loses its value... Here is my soap server setup:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
ini_set('session.auto_start', 0); 
ini_set('always_populate_raw_post_data', 1);

global $config_dir;

session_start();

/*if(!$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA){
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = file_get_contents('php://input');
  }*/

$server = new SoapServer("{$config_dir['template']}import.wsdl");  
$server->setClass('import');
$server->setPersistence(SOAP_PERSISTENCE_SESSION);
$server->handle();
```

2) Problem is that I passed this to the server:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://import.ingatlan.net/wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$xml.='<xml>';
$xml.='<referens>';
$xml.='<original_id><![CDATA[DH-2]]></original_id>';
$xml.='<name>Valaki</name>';
$xml.='<email><![CDATA[valaki@example.com]]></email>';
$xml.='<phone><![CDATA[06-30/111-2222]]></phone>';
$xml.='</referens>';
$xml.='</xml>';


$tarray = array("type" => 1, "xml" => $xml);
try {
    $s = $client->sendXml( $tarray );
    print "$s<br>";
}
catch(SOAPFault $exception) { 

    print "<br>--- SOAP exception :<br>{$exception}<br>---<br>";

    print "<br>LAST REQUEST :<br>";
    var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
    print "<br>---<br>";
    print "<br>LAST RESPONSE :<br>".$client->__getLastResponse();

}
```

So passed an Array of informations to the server. Then I got this exception:
LAST REQUEST :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><type>Array</type><xml/></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can you see the Array word between the type tag? Seems  that the client only passed a reference or something like this. So I totally missed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the SOAP extension is expecting a string, but you're giving it an array. It then tries to convert the array into a string, resulting in "Array". I don't have time to check right now what the extension does  you write `$client->sendXml( $tarray );`, but try to use instead:

```
$client->__soapCall("sendXml", $tarray);
```

Comment: The call is working! Now I see the xml string itself and not the Array text! But I got a SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document in....

I made the xml paramater in this way:
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
<referens>
<original_id>DH-2</original_id>
<name>Valaki</name>
<email>valaki@rusznyak.com</email>
<phone>06-30/375-3177</phone>
</referens>
</xml>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

Comment: @Tamas Pass it the string directly, don't wrap it in a SimpleXMLElement object. I've checked the WSDL and it expects a string.

Comment: @Artefacto: I passed the string itself, but I got the same exception :( You can see the test page here: http://import.ingatlan.net/sky

Comment: Another interesting thing is that I try to use the __soapCall for another public function but it throws an error. It seems only working on the sendXml function.

Comment: @Tomas Well, that's a service-specific error. Your request is provoking some kind of error in the server (which, oddly, seems to be running xdebug).

Comment: @Artefacto - I found the problem finally! :) The SoapServer pointed a different WSDL file than the SoapClient. (I got a developer and a live copy....)
But I accepst your answer because I find the solution based on that!